# How to overlay GLSurfaceView over a MapView in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to create a simple Map based application in android ,where i can display my current position.Instead of overlaying a simple Image on the MapView to represent the position, i want to overlay the GLSurfaceView on the MapView. But i don't know how to achieve this. Is there any way to do that?. Please anybody knows the solution help me.

Comment: Hi Rajapandian, Have you found a solution for your post ? because, now I'm in same situation. can you please help me ?

Answer (score 5):

I was stuck on a similar problem until I looked at the documentation and realized that `MapView` extends `ViewGroup`, so overlaying a `GlSurfaceView` actually ends up being pretty trivial.

`MapView.addView(...)` and `MapView.LayoutParams` allow you to some pretty useful things like place a `View` at a specific `GeoPoint` on the map.

More documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.LayoutParams.html

Here's what I did:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

    MapView map_view = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);

    CustomGlView gl_view = new CustomGlView(this);

    // This is where the action happens.
    map_view.addView(gl_view, new MapView.LayoutParams(
            MapView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            MapView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            0,0, 
            MapView.LayoutParams.TOP_LEFT
            )
        );
}
```

Plus also do what the solution above states.  I sub-classed GlSurfaceView, so mine looks slightly different:

```
public CustomGlView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    YourCustomGlRenderer renderer = new YourCustomGlRenderer();
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    setRenderer(renderer);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    // Have to do this or else 
    // GlSurfaceView wont be transparent.
    setZOrderOnTop(true);  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the GLSurfaceView and set its EGLConfigChooser like this:

`glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);`

then set the format of the holder to translucent

`glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);`

and add the GLSurfaceView and the MapView to the Layout

`setContentView(glSurfaceView);`

`addContentView(mapView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));`

finally in your renderer you'll need to set the clear color so it is transparent

`gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: I applied this approach but rotation does not apply. Mapview stays stable.