# GLSurfaceView over Google MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es-2.0, android-mapview, glsurfaceview

Need to overlay two views. A GLSurfaceView and a MapView. My map view is following the code from the following Github location:

[Android Google Maps v2](https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551)

The GLSurfaceView needs to be on top of the map view which I believe I just use

zOrderOnTop(true);

However, I do not know how to add this second view to the class. I've been attempting to work with this Stack Overflow question:

[How to overlay GLSurfaceView over a MapView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825539/how-to-overlay-glsurfaceview-over-a-mapview-in-android)

but have not been able to get it to work... Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Also, from observing the developers reference guide about MapViews, there is a note that says: "You are advised NOT to add children to this view." 
Would overlaying a GLSurfaceView be adding a child to the MapView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question to this one that had my source code. I seemed to have found a solution that works currently however, not sure how elegant it is...

[GLSurfaceView not appearing over MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402623/glsurfaceview-not-appearing-over-mapview/30493960#30493960)

Basically, I separated my views (MapView and GLSurfaceView) into two fragments. Then I called them from an Activity. The fragments occupied the same area and the GLSurfaceView is called after the MapView.

This works for me. Please let me know if there is a simpler/more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

in android studio you can create map activity

```js
                    MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, mapFragment)
                            .commit();
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                            // do some thing 
                        }
                    });
```

or try this tutorial 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/