# Showing vector tiles from own WMS?

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es-2.0, geojson, vector-tiles

We want to show our vector tiles on google map, we already done with png tiles with google map SDK's tile provider but we need it with vector tiles GeoJson.
I have found some solution like 
[this :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402623/glsurfaceview-not-appearing-over-mapview/30493960#30493960)

here it has these codes :

```
public class GoogleMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    final Context context = this;

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);

    if(SettingsActivity.mUnits){
        setContentView(R.layout.google_maps_tracker_metric);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.google_maps_tracker);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    // Get both fragments shown on the same screen
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    GoogleMapsTracker fragment;
    fragment = GoogleMapsTracker.newInstance();

    GoogleMapsOGLES fragmentOGL;
    fragmentOGL = GoogleMapsOGLES.newInstance();

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.gl, fragmentOGL);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() { 
    super.onDestroy(); 
}
```

but this is not complete and has some layouts and classes that not provided.
did anyone do this or can help me with it ?

Comment: what kind of problems do you have in `Tile 
getTile(int x, int y, int zoom)` method?

Comment: i don't have any problem with get tile with png tiles provider as i told. id need render vector tiles

Comment: then return a `Tile` that contains both your png content and vector content

Comment: the response of wms server is json , how i can render it ? tile provider return an image.

Comment: you have to parse it and use `Canvas` api

Comment: can you help me to do this ? it's very important for us

Comment: either use `JSONObject` or `JSONReader` and depending on parsed content call `Canvas#draw*` methods

Comment: it's ok to parse json . but we don't know the steps . how parse geojson and draw it in google map

Comment: no one can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Google Maps Android API doesn't support vector tiles yet. In Google issue tracker you can find a feature request to add support for vector tiles (currently 6 stars):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830251

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications from Google.